# Anonymous function returns too many input arguments

Tags: matlab

I separately wrote the following function

```
function [func] = fwet_1(~)
func = @(gm1,Sc,Scmax) (Sc/Scmax)^gm1;
end
```

and when I to run `fwet_1(0.23,1,3)` it returns

```
Error using fwet_1
Too many input arguments.
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fwet_1` takes a single input, which must be ignored by the function. Your syntax is calling `fwet_1` itself with three inputs, not the function handle it returns.

You can call the function handle like this (literally any single argument is allowed in place of `[]`):

```
x = fwet_1([])
x(0.23,1,3)
```

If your function really does nothing but return a function handle, skip the function entirely, or remove the unnecessary level of nesting. E.g.:

```
function [val] = fwet_1(gm1,Sc,Scmax)
val = (Sc/Scmax)^gm1;
end
```

If you need a function handle, just use `@fwet_1`. There's no difference between a regular function and an anonymous one when you pass it around.

Comment: One minor correction: the function takes one input argument that is ignored (`~` means ignore this input).

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Thanks for the catch. I've updated the prose and the usage example.